# Automatically detect and use indentation style of current file

Tags: vim

I work on several projects that are using different indentation levels (2 spaces / 4 spaces / tabs...).

Is it possible to make Vim automatically detect the indentation style of the current file and use it, that's-to-say, can the Tab key be made "intelligent" indenting the "right way" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim doesn't do that by default but Ingo Karkat's [IndentConsistencyCop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690) does.

Answer (score 0):

Good question，I'm facing the same problem too， and recently I wrote such a vim plugin for myself：https://github.com/luochen1990/indent-detector.vim

it has the following features:

- detect mixed indent and echo warnning on bufEnter and bufWrite automatically.
- switch setting about indenting to fit the current indenting style automatically.
- detecting time is limited, so you don't need to worry about opening huge files.

I think it is well designed, and need to be known, post an issue on github if you have any suggestion :)